# How to find sorted data by elastic search - spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I got an error while sorting data using elastic search. I will show you my code..

**this is my model class:**

```
@Document(indexName="book",type="book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String releaseDate;
    public Book() {
        super();
    }
    public Book(String id, String title, String author, String releaseDate) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }
    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", author=" + author + ", releaseDate=" + releaseDate + "]";
    }

}
```

**this is the query i used to show sorted data based on id:**

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("id").order(SortOrder.DESC))
                .withPageable(PageRequest.of(index, 4))
                .build();
        List<Book> res = elasticTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, Book.class);
        Iterator<Book> itr = res.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Book book = (Book) itr.next();
            System.out.println(book);
        }
```

**and i got this error message :**

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseFailure(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:293) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:133) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.onPhaseDone(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:254) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase.onShardFailure(InitialSearchPhase.java:101) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase.access$100(InitialSearchPhase.java:48) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase$2.lambda$onFailure$1(InitialSearchPhase.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase.maybeFork(InitialSearchPhase.java:175) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase.access$000(InitialSearchPhase.java:48) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.InitialSearchPhase$2.onFailure(InitialSearchPhase.java:221) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListenerResponseHandler.handleException(ActionListenerResponseHandler.java:53) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService$ConnectionCountingHandler.handleException(SearchTransportService.java:462) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$ContextRestoreResponseHandler.handleException(TransportService.java:1103) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.processException(TransportService.java:1215) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$DirectResponseChannel.sendResponse(TransportService.java:1189) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TaskTransportChannel.sendResponse(TaskTransportChannel.java:60) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$ChannelActionListener.onFailure(HandledTransportAction.java:112) ~[na:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$1.onFailure(SearchService.java:319) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$1.onResponse(SearchService.java:313) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$1.onResponse(SearchService.java:307) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$4.doRun(SearchService.java:1117) ~[na:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:759) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.TimedRunnable.doRun(TimedRunnable.java:41) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.NotSerializableExceptionWrapper: : Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [id] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.guessRootCauses(ElasticsearchException.java:657) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:131) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [id] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead.
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.TextFieldMapper$TextFieldType.fielddataBuilder(TextFieldMapper.java:670) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexFieldDataService.getForField(IndexFieldDataService.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryShardContext.getForField(QueryShardContext.java:166) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.FieldSortBuilder.build(FieldSortBuilder.java:349) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortBuilder.buildSort(SortBuilder.java:153) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:823) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:656) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:631) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeDfsPhase(SearchService.java:325) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.access$000(SearchService.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService$1.onResponse(SearchService.java:311) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar:6.4.3]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

i found the reason for this error.by default fielddata is disabled on text fields but i dont know how to enable field data.How can i set fielddata=true on "id"?Can i sort data in method-name based query?

Comment: Try SortBuilders.fieldSort("id.keyword")

Comment: Great. I added the comment as the answer. Can you please accept it as the correct answer? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use

```
SortBuilders.fieldSort("id.keyword")
```

to sort by the keywords of this field.